# C++, Class: Out-of-line declaration of a member error?

Tags: c++, arrays, class, compiler-errors, declaration

I am trying to create a dynamic array using a class. In my header file I have the following code:

```
#ifndef DYNAMICARRAY
#define DYNAMICARRAY
#include <iostream>

class Array 
{

public:

    Array(); // Constructor - Initialises the data members
    ~Array(); // Destructor - That deletes the memory allocated to the array
    void addTings (float itemValue); // which adds new items to the end of the array
    float getTings (int index); // which returns the item at the index
    void size(); // which returns the number of items currently in the array

private:

    int arraySize;
    float  *floatPointer = nullptr;
};

#endif // DYNAMICARRAY
```

And in my .cpp file I have the following code:

```
#include "DYNAMICARRAY.h"

Array::Array()
{
    floatPointer = new float[arraySize];
}

Array::~Array()
{
    delete[] floatPointer;
}

void Array::addTings (float itemValue);  // Out-of-line declaration ERROR
{
    std::cout << "How many items do you want to add to the array";
    std::cin >> arraySize;
}

float Array::getTings (int index);    // Out-of-line declaration ERROR
{

}

void Array::size()
{

}
```

I am getting a Out-of-line declaration of a member must be a definition compile error on both of the lines:

```
float Array::getTings (int index);
```

and

```
void Array::addTings (float itemValue);
```

Does anyone have any idea why? I thought I had linked the header file to the cpp file correctly but obviously not?

Comment: Semicolons. Too much semicolons...

Comment: What happens if I copy your array object?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should remove the semicolons in the cpp file.

```
void Array::addTings (float itemValue);
```

should be

```
void Array::addTings (float itemValue)
```

Correct code is:

```
void Array::addTings (float itemValue)  // Out-of-line declaration ERROR
{
std::cout << "How many items do you want to add to the array";
std::cin >> arraySize;


}

float Array::getTings (int index)    // Out-of-line declaration ERROR
{

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of the semi-colons in the definition of the functions.  See below

```
void Array::addTings (float itemValue);
{
}
float Array::getTings (int index);
{
}

void Array::addTings (float itemValue)
{
}
float Array::getTings (int index)
{
}
```